# About Simple Instruction Count Tool in Pin Tool

Tags: macos, intel, codesign, control-flow

I begin to study intel pin tool recently, and I am a new comer to this group.

I try to count the instruction, which is exactly as tutorial says, but I received the error message. All is listed below:

> **../../../pin -t obj-intel64/inscount0.so -- /bin/ls**
>
> **E:Pin does not support signed applications. To "unsign" the application, copy the original application to a different location,
>   then use: codesign -fs-**

About the "codesign" method, I have tried, but nothing happens. Error is still there.

I have searched online and found no appearance. I wonder if anyone in this group have seen such error message before?

I could provide more information about my PC environment if in need.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's probably due to security measures in your system. 
Try to create a simple 'hello world' binary and run the pin tool and see what you get. The problem might be security in the binaries inside /bin/*

After you create your simple hello world program, you can do the following:

```
g++ -o hello_world hello_world.cpp [this is the step to build your program]
../../../pin -t obj-intel64/inscount0.so -- ./hello_world
```

By the way, you can learn more about code signing in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_signing